# Finding the busiest time period in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this.

```
trip_start        trip_end           day_of_month 
2008/1/15 0:01    2008/1/15 0:35     15
2008/1/15 0:02    2008/1/15 0:08     15
2008/1/15 0:03    2008/1/15 0:19     15
2008/1/15 0:05    2008/1/15 0:16     15
2009/2/16 0:01    2009/2/16 0:35     16
2009/2/16 0:02    2009/2/16 0:08     16
2009/2/16 0:03    2009/2/16 0:19     16
2009/2/16 0:05    2009/2/16 0:16     16

...
```

How do I find the max number of trips in an hour (starts and finishes in the same day, doesn't have to start on exact hours) on each day of the month? 
I tried to use

```
month_group = data.groupby("dayofmonth")
```

But I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: Trips should be longer as one hour? What is expected output from input? Is data sample [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: How do you classify busiest hour? Is it having the most number of trips ending in that hour? Most trips starting in it?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't converted the columns to `datetime` objects yet you should do this first:

```
df["time_start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["trip_start"])
df["time_end"] = pd.to_datetime(df["trip_end"])
```

Next I will assume you define a trip as being in an hour if it ends in an hour. (You can change this to starts in hour by simply changing `trip_end` to `trip_start` in the following... if it's by some other criteria let me know)

```
df["hour"] = df["trip_end"].dt.hour
df = df.groupby("dayofmonth")["hour"].count()
```